# How can I get account balance in adwords scripts?

Tags: google-ads-api

How can I get account balance in adwords scripts?

I write some script for generation report. It almost done, but I can not find how get account payment balance?

Comment: Three years on, there is no easily-read balance sheet for Google AdWords. Whatever the reason for that, I'm selling my shares in the company!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access any account info from Scripts.

Best workaround would be having a Google sheet that you manually update when you add funds to the account and then read spend from AdWords scripts to subtract from your balance from the google sheet.

It doesn't work exactly though because of small little refunds from fraudulent clicks but may be close enough for you depending on your needs